# Can I avoid the foreign key properties in my entity?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have the following classes:

```
   public class Bicycle
    {
        public int BicycleId { get; set; }
        public DateTime YearOfManufacture { get; set; }
        public int BicycleManufactuerId { get; set; }
        public BicycleManufacturer BicycleManufacturer { get; set; }
    }

    public class BicycleManufacturer
    {
        public int BicycleManufacturerId { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

Each `Bicycle` must have a `BicycleManufacturer` (1:1). There could be some `BicycleManufacturer` that isn't associate with any `Bicycle`. Most will be associated with multiple `Bicycle` entities.

I have the following fluent API code to set up the FK relationship:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Bicycle>()
        .HasRequired(a => a.BicycleManufacturer)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(u => u.BicycleManufactuerId);
```

This all seems to work fine. However, I would really like to remove the `BicycleManufacturerId` property from the `Bicycle` entity. It's only there to establish the FK relationship. Is there a way I can create the proper FK relationship if I remove this property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the property and use the mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Bicycle>()
    .HasRequired(a => a.BicycleManufacturer)
    .WithMany()
    .Map(m => m.MapKey("BicycleManufactuerId"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it by convention by adding the relationship on the other side as a collection.

```
public class Bicycle
    {
        public int BicycleId { get; set; }
        public DateTime YearOfManufacture { get; set; }
        public int BicycleManufactuerId { get; set; }
        public BicycleManufacturer BicycleManufacturer { get; set; }
    }

    public class BicycleManufacturer
    {
        public int BicycleManufacturerId { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Bicycle> Bicycles { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```